# c# A sorting by columnheader problem in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is created by using Datatable. When I try to give a name to a column if this name includes a ","  like this : DataColumn dc8 = new DataColumn("22,5"); and if  i try to sort this column by 
columnheader it gives error but i change the "," to "." like : DataColumn dc8 = new DataColumn("22.5"); it works.

i need to make the code works in first situation

Comment: not working for me it says not a valid sequence input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer at  [DataTable sorting with Datacolumn Name with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097203/datatable-sorting-with-datacolumn-name-with-comma) does work.

Try this in your sorting method:

```
protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                dataTable.Columns["22,5"].ColumnName = "Temporary";
                dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Temporary DESC";
                dataTable = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
                dataTable.Columns["Temporary"].ColumnName = "22,5";

                GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```